# Running Event Handlers in Xamarin Forms while app is closed, such as receiving Messages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr

I am looking to catch messages via SignalR when sent to another device. If the second device has the app closed, how can the closed app still receive the message and show notifications for that message?

I am running my messages using SignalR. I have an event that is in my ChatHub that handles my SignalR `OnMessageReceived` event, but when the app is killed, I don't get any notification such as when my app is still open.

It works 100% when my app is in the foreground, but as soon as the app is killed, it no longer works. Can anyone point me in a direction to where I can read up about how to solve something like this?

Comment: You have to read about push notifications, cloud messaging.

Comment: @AliAhmad Thank you, I shall take a look at that!